# Using Signal R with Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, windows-services, signalr-hub

I have created a signalR server and i can be able to connect from console application but I have to connect SignalR from Windows Service

```
public partial class WindowsServiceManager : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        HubConnection connection;
        public WindowsServiceManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 5000; //number in milisecinds
            timer.Enabled = true;
            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
              .WithUrl("https://localhost:7082/InstallService")
              .Build();
            connection.Closed += async (error) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                await connection.StartAsync();
            };
            connection.StartAsync();
            InstallService();
        }
        
        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
            InstallService();


        }
       
        public void InstallService()
        {
            WriteToFile("İnside");
            
            connection.Closed += async (error) =>
            {
                 await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                 await connection.StartAsync();
            };
            WriteToFile("before start");
            connection.StartAsync();
            WriteToFile("after start");
            connection.On<string, string>("InstallService", (serviceName, serviceURL) =>
            {
                WriteToFile("inside signal");
                WriteToFile(serviceURL + serviceName);

            });

        }
    }
```

Normaly with code below above signalR interact succesfully but I can't Run it via Windows Server

```
 connection.On<string, string>("InstallService", (serviceName, serviceURL) =>
            {
                WriteToFile("inside signal");
                WriteToFile(serviceURL + serviceName);

            });
```

I Want to reach SignalR from the Windows Service i  created.

Answer (score 2):

Update!

I tried to publish server online. It worked well. It seems like problem occured due to server work as a local host.